# useEffect not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [count, setCount]=useState(0);
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("count inside hook is ", count);
  },[count]);
  if(count<10)
    setCount(count+1); // setCount(count=>count+1)
```

I have this code, I expected to the console for every count, but I can only see console log for count=10.

My understanding is that given a dependency array, useEffect must be called when the object inside it changes, but this doesn't happens here. Can someone please explain why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `setCount(count+1);` You're calling this in the middle of rendering, is that correct?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set state during rendering, then it essentially aborts the current render. After you return, react doesn't push the interim changes to the dom, and doesn't run effects. Instead, it starts the new render with the new state. Eventually, once you hit 10, you stop setting state mid-render, and that final render can complete and run its useEffect.

Comment: Thanks, would call of multiple setStates inside useEffect will also get aborted? Say I have useEffect(()=>{setx(a);sety(b);setz(c)},[a,b,c]) x,y,z,a,b,c all are states.

Comment: The useEffect runs after rendering. Since rendering is not currently going on, there is nothing to abort. If you set state 3 times in the effect, this will result in 1 render.